# How to Solve “Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 58”?

Tags: c#-4.0, connection-string

I am facing an issue in my windows Form Application at Sql Connection it says

“Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 58”

my connection string is given below i want to deploy this application on client machine without installing Sql server on his machine

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="vhclecs" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Movies;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Vehicle Management System.mdf';Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

i have also used

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="vhclecs" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Movies;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Vehicle Management System.mdf';Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

but when i used this i got same error just index 38

Comment: also i am using windows authentication

Comment: Why there is an additional tick `'` after `.mdf`? Did you try removing that?

Comment: ohh thanks solved :)